# Angularjs and Intel XDK doesn't mix well

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-framework, intel-xdk

I've been trying to build an app with Angularjs and Intel XDK, but it seems that XDK strips some tags from the html so Angularjs won't work.

Here's the code:

```
<script src='intelxdk.js'></script>
<script src='vendors/angular.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var onDeviceReady=function(){
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        var bApp = angular.module('bApp', []);
        bApp.controller('MenuCtrl', function ($scope) {
           $scope.test = 'Hello world!'; 
        });

    };
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
</script>

<div ng-app="bApp">
    <div id="MenuCtrl" ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
        {{test}}
    </div>

</div>
```

And here's the error message in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module bApp 
due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'bApp' is not available! 
You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as 
the second argument.
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a matter of scope it seems!

Moving bApp-related code out of the onDeviceReady function solved the problem.